# USB cable model for Kodak EasyShare Z740

Tags: cable

I've lost the original USB cable for my [Kodak EasyShare Z740](http://www.kodak.com/eknec/PageQuerier.jhtml?pq-path=6551&pq-locale=en_US&_requestid=5373), and I can't figure out which model I should replace it with.

I did not find the original parts, as the camera is pretty old. I did find the [cable on the Kodak site](http://www.kodak.com/eknec/PageQuerier.jhtml?pq-path=6558&pq-locale=en_US&cameraEkNumber=EKN029416&skuID=S19541&Visible=false&navCategory=EKN029416), but I I've tried both mini-USB and micro-USB and neither fit.

[image: cable]

Alternatively, bonus points for pointing out a dealer in *Bucharest, Romania* which has the original part.

---

*N.B.* I do use a card reader now, but I find it more convenient to use the cable.

Answer (score 1):

eBay Germany: [Mini USB Kabel Kodak Easyshare Z740 Datenkabel Z-740](http://cgi.ebay.de/Mini-USB-Kabel-Kodak-Easyshare-Z740-Datenkabel-Z-740_W0QQitemZ310151117821QQcmdZViewItemQQptZDE_Elektronik_Computer_Foto_Camcorder_Foto_Camcorderzubeh%C3%B6r_PM?hash=item4836727bfd&_trksid=p3286.c0.m14&_trkparms=65%3A12|66%3A2|39%3A1|72%3A1229|293%3A1|294%3A50#shId)

EUR 11.95 plus shipping within Europe EUR 2.50.

Answer (score 1):

[Found it ultra cheap on UK EBay](http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/USB-Cable%2FLead-For-Kodak-EasyShare-Z700-Z730-Z740-P850_W0QQitemZ130314050922QQcmdZViewItemQQimsxZ20090621?IMSfp=TL090621148003r14524).

If you don't like it, just google for "z740 usb cable europe".

Answer (score 1):

I actually have that cable from an old camera. I do not use it so you are welcome to it if you really want it.  It will be a week at least before I get back to where the cable is stored tho.  If you are in a hurry, you should consider getting it elsewhere.